# Fetching resources from google analytics services using HTTPS by Wix fetch function

Tags: fetch, google-analytics-api, velo

How should I fetch data using [Wix-fetch](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-fetch) function?

I followed this [google analytics API tutorial](http://thisistony.com/blog/googleanalytics/google-analytics-api-oauth-ever-wondered-how-to-get-the-access_token/), this tutorial using post function for getting JSON data, I used WIX fetch function to get JSON file, but the return object is undefined.
What did I miss?

```
fetch( "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
  "method": "post",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
 'body' : JSON.stringify({
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': URLCode,
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://www.mydomain.or/ga/oauth2callback'
  })
} )
  .then( (httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
      return httpResponse.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
  } )
  .then( (json) => console.log(json.someKey) )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

UPDATE

**STEP 1**
I used this URL to generate the CODE

```
wixLocation.to("https://accounts.google.or/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&redirect_uri=https://www.mydomain.or/ga/oauth2callback/&access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

I get the CODE from the callback URL
[image]

**Step 2**
I used this code for the HTTP postman request

[image]

The redirect URI in step 1 and 2 is the following (the second one):
[image]

Comment: are you sure you are using correct endpoint? Try with `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` and check what is httpResponse in console.

Comment: did you manage to get the access token via Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
There needs to be an exact match between the redirect URI configured in the client id in the google developers console and the URL to get the code authorization.
[image]
The URL should be built as shown in the tutorial you linked (if you need a refresh token, you can add the access_type=offline)

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>

After you enter the URL, you will be provided with an authorization window. Once you authorize, you will be redirected to the <redirect_uri> you provided earlier. You will find the code as the first parameter in the URL query. e.g. <redirect_uri>/?code=<auth_code> ...

Since the access token is for one-time use only, if you will need it again, you will have to get a new <auth_code>.

Step 2 (Postman query example):
[image]

If you got the access_token correctly and you want to check now with WIX. Get a new <auth_code> (as said, the access token is given once) and set the code as follows:

```js
    import { fetch} from 'wix-fetch';
    
    $w.onReady(function () {
    
    const data = `grant_type=authorization_code&code=<your_authorization_code>&client_id=<your_client_id>&client_secret=<your_client_secret>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>`;
    
    fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': data
    })
    .then((httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
    return httpResponse.json();
    } else {
    
    return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
    })
    .then((json) => console.log(json.access_token))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
```

[image]

Comment: I added to the URL "access_type=offline"  and use your code from step 2 but nothing changed, is there something else you did?

Comment: after step 1, did you manage to get the access token with Postman?

Comment: I didn't try to get an access token with postman I only tried Wix fetch

Comment: you can check here https://pasteboard.co/JyeIUMi.png if you want to try out first with Postman (I highly recommend) . btw, i saw there was a missing = between code and <your_authorization_code> i fixed the typo in the edit.

Comment: I changed the = sign in the first time 
I print the body before using : 
`grant_type=authorization_code&code=4/5wXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://www.mydomain.or/ga/oauth2callback`
Why are you using redirect_uri from local host and not use your domain ?

Comment: did you try with postman? if step 1 was done right, postman should retrieve the correct access token. if it works, we can check what went wrong in step 2.

Comment: Step 1 is done, step, but step 5 Not working with Postman or Wix fetch , I get 
 {
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}

Comment: are you sure you have a 'grant_type' key with a value of 'authorization_code'? it seems missing by the error you got

Comment: Yes, the 'grant_type' key has an 'authorization_code' value like this, Is this OK?
https://pasteboard.co/JyjUZFZ.png

Comment: Ok we are advancing. You need to also add the client_secret and the redirect_uri, you can compare to the screenshot i attached eariler in the comments. You can attach screenshot again afterwards.

Comment: I compared your body request to mine and it looks the same.
https://pasteboard.co/JykhCmq.png

Comment: 1) what is the redirect uri that is configured in your client id in https://console.developers.google.com/? the one you have there, should be the one you are passing in Postman or WIX in redirect_uri (mine was just for example) 2) Can you share the url you sent in step 1?

Comment: I used "https://www.mydomain.or/ga/oauth2callback" URI. and the URL in from the fist step is this: wixLocation.to("https://accounts.google.or/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.or/auth/analytics%20https://www.googleapis.or/auth/userinfo.email&redirect_uri=https://www.mydomain.or/ga/oauth2callback/&access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  (.com changed to .or becoase of StackOverflow T&C)

Comment: ok, so in your postman setup, verify that redirect_uri is https://www.mydomain.or/ga/oauth2callback and not http://localhost:8080 (take the full paths). did that help? also verify that the redirect uri is present in the client id in google console https://pasteboard.co/JylGyRS.jpg

Comment: I already did it for the first time, it doesn't succeed.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer. Did you try to regenerate the authorization code? I suggest doing so and then trying with Postman again

Comment: I changed nothing.... just try again today morning and it's working on the postman. :)

Comment: If you managed to run in postman, did you try to regenerate the auth code and try out in wix? btw, don't forget to clear cookies between postman runs.

Comment: Yes, it's also working on WIX, yesterday night I removed the app permission from here  https://myaccount.google.com/permissions, so maybe this is the reason. Thank you so much.